# MySQL: COUNT is too high, because of multiple entrys in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

i got a statement like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( epoa.eclass ) AS counts, epoa.eclass, map.eclass_description
FROM `db2`.`articles` epoa,
`db1`.`ECLASS_UNSPSC` map

where epoa.eclass = map.eclass 

GROUP BY epoa.eclass
ORDER BY counts DESC
```

Explanation: Map (ECLASS_UNSPSC) has the description for the eclass (number). Sometimes there are more than one description, so i have an incorrent COUNT. How can i get just one description instead of multiple? so that my count is correct?

Comment: What do you want to count? Can you remove  map.eclass_description from the query? My be you could try grouping by map.eclass.

Comment: `How can i get just one description instead of multiple?` => Which one do you want?

Comment: thanks. My Problem is: The Table ECLASS_UNSPSC (map) has translations/describtions for each unique eclass. So first i had my Statement just counted the eclass and give back the counts and eclass. But the eclass is a long number and noone knows what that is, so i need the describtion for that number. I get this from the table i mentioned above. but this table has multiple entrys and that destroys the count. So i need to filter, like i only want one (the first?!) translation or anything like that... hope u understand that.

Comment: You can get them all with `GROUP_CONCAT(map.eclass_description)`

Answer (score 4):

The `COUNT()` aggregate function does exactly that: count. It doesn't make any assumption about what you'd consider to be a duplicate.

If you want to number of *unique* values for `epoa.eclass`, replace it with:

```
COUNT( DISTINCT epoa.eclass ) AS counts
```

Comment: thanks. My Problem is: The Table ECLASS_UNSPSC (map) has translations/describtions for each unique eclass. So first i had my Statement just counted the eclass and give back the counts and eclass. But the eclass is a long number and noone knows what that is, so i need the describtion for that number. I get this from the table i mentioned above. but this table has multiple entrys and that destroys the count. So i need to filter, like i only want one (the first?!) translation or anything like that... hope u understand that.

Comment: If you have e.g. A, A, A, A, A and you want your count to be 3, you'll need to fully rewrite your question and explain what the query returns and what your count criterion is. We cannot read your mind.